# Función asincrona con node no obtiene el resultado de consulta SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Quiero obtener todos los registros de mi tabla `rol`, la consulta funciona cuando la ejecuto directamente en la ruta, pero al colocar la consulta SQL en un archivo externo ya no devuelve el resultado, en su lugar obtengo `undefined`.

**Conexión a la base de datos.**

```js
const { database } = require('./keys');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const pool = mysql.createPool(database);

pool.getConnection((err, con) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`-> db status: ${con.state}`);
    con.release();
    return;
})
pool.query = promisify(pool.query);
module.exports = pool;
```

**route.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let rolController = require('../controllers/rolController');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let roles = await rolController.allRol();
    console.log(roles);
    res.send(roles);
})

module.exports = router;
```

La consulta SQL se encuentra en el siguiente archivo `rolController.js`

```js
let db = require('../database');
module.exports = {
    allRol: (req, res) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM rol where rol_state = 1', (err, row) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            return row;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: cambia `return row`; por `res(row)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema que tienes es en el archivo `rollController.js` que no devuelves el resultado de la query, es decir, si la devuelves pero dentro del scope de la consulta a la base de datos por lo que no afecta al scope de la función `allRol`, por ese motivo no te devuelve nada. Como estas usando la utilidad `promisify`, que transformas los callbacks por promesas, usare el Async/Await para resolver dichas promesas y devolver el resultado, capturando los posibles errores (asunto que deberías de contemplar por sí ocurrieran).

Te pongo el código que debería de funcionarte:

```
let db = require('../database');
module.exports = {
    allRol: async (req, res) => { 
        try{

           return await db.query('SELECT * FROM rol where rol_state = 1')
        }catch (e){
           //Capturas el posible error y devuelve lo que necesites. Yo retorno el mensaje del error.
           return e.message
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que con esto te haya podido ayudar a resolver tu problema, en tal caso no dudes en preguntar.

Saludos

PD: en el archivo `router.js`no te haría falta usar Async/Await ya que no estas trabajando con Promises en ese momento:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let rolController = require('../controllers/rolController');

router.get('/',(req, res) => {
    let roles = rolController.allRol();
    console.log(roles);
    res.send(roles);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hola @planta4 gracias por la respuesta, tengo otra inquietud. El echo de que use `promisify` significa que ya no necesito el callback en una consulta? `db.query('SELECT ...., (err, row) => { //respuesta  })`.. es decir ya no es necesario ? únicamente debería manejarlo con el `try/catch`?

Comment: Lo que hace la utilidad `promisify` es transformar todas las llamadas asíncronas de `mysql` en Promises, de esa forma puedes trabajar con `.then()` y `.catch` si usas Promesas o con Async/Await, en este ultimo caso, no es necesario englobarlo con try-catch pero es una buena practica para poder capturar los posibles errores del sistema y así controlar el flujo del sistema.